# Unable to upload video from flutter to server php?

Tags: php, flutter

I tried to upload a video. Got the message "Video uploaded" and NO video file received in 'uploads' folder.  When I tried to upload an image file, it works (uploaded image file has arrived in the 'uploads' folder). My code doesn't work with the video file. How to make it receive a video file?

This is a dart file.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Upload MySQL',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  File _video;

  Future getVideoGallery() async{
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _video = imageFile;
    });
  }

  Future getVideoCamera() async{
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
            setState(() {
      _video = imageFile;
    });
  }

  Future uploadVideo(File videoFile) async{
    var uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.1/ABC/uploadVideo.php");
    var request = new MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromPath("video", videoFile.path);
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      print("Video uploaded");
    }else{
      print("Video upload failed");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Upload Image"),),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           _video==null
              ? new Text("No video selected!")
              : new Text("video is selected"),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                  onPressed: getVideoGallery,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.videocam),
                  onPressed: getVideoCamera,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("UPLOAD video"),
                  onPressed:(){
                    uploadVideo(_video);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is php file.

```
<?php

include 'conn.php';

$video=$_FILES['video']['name'];
$videoPath="uploads/".$video;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'],$videoPath);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, finally, I found solution. That is to increase upload limit in php.ini. 
I can upload images but not videos because video files are larger than 2MB of max upload limit.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem using the HTTP library
You can use the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package instead.
It supports large files and works fine with me.

```
sendVideoDio(String kMainUrl, XFile video) async {
String filePath = video.path;
String fileName = 'any name';

try {
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    "file":
    await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename:fileName),
  });
  Response response =
  await Dio().post(kMainUrl, data: formData);
  print("File upload response: $response");
  print(response.data['message']);
} catch (e) {
  print("Exception Caught: $e");
}
```

}

Comment: Also note that unless server allows large file size uploads, nothing can work.

Comment: That's right but my problem was not with the server, it was the HTTP package.